# Does "from ... to" here represent time scale?

Tags: grammar, parsing

> For governments the temptation is to turn the clock back to limit the economic damage, **from the collapse of city-centre cafés to the $16bn budget shortfall that New York’s subway system faces.** Britain’s government has tried to cajole workers back to the office. But rather than resist technological change, it is far better to anticipate its consequences. Two priorities stand out.

---

I would like to think about it as a reference to damage, but there is a comma also there is no collocation of "limit from", and thinking it as a time scale is weird to me.

How should I understand it grammatically?

article link :　https://www.economist.com/leaders/2020/09/12/is-the-office-finished

Comment: It’s a range of responses, not a range of times.

Comment: I think it's a range of economic damages provoking the response to turn back time, more than the response, but it's definitely not time. The sentence seems a little clumsy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.  In original usage, "From...to..." would refer to distance, and has now evolved to stand for any kind of distance.  Physical, time, statistical, size, or broadly conceptual like the example.